# HTML5 <audio> stalling in firefox

Tags: html, audio

Hi I am working on a site which utilizes the new HTML5 audio element. I have both .mp3s and .wav files ready so that it can play in safari and firefox. Firefox loads the page up in a couple seconds but the audio stalls during playback. The page takes longer to load in safari but the playback is perfect. Have the .wav files been currupted somehow, or is firefox assuming that they are loaded before they actually are? I was really excited to use HTML5 should I just use flash?
[Here is the page for reference](http://www.yesaffirmations.com)

Answer (score 1):

.WAV files can easily get huge, as they are uncompress... you'd better be using .OGG files. Here is the list of [supported audio formats by browsers](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/).

If you don't know how to convert sounds from one format to another, you can use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). It also has a [graphical interface for Windows](http://winff.org/html_new/).